# Why wrong function was linked by the linker?

Tags: c, linux, linker, linkage

I am very confused about the following situation:

I have Linux project (which is written in c) that uses a static library A to get an executable. In this static library A there is a c code which calls [sem_init](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_init.3.html) from  Linux include. There is include to semaphore.h in the .c file, the file compiled using GCC without warnings. I use ld linker.

Everything was fine until I have added unintentionally a new module(which compiled to the static library B) to the project. New code has a function with the same name (sem_init) but a different signature. Code from A does not include .h file from B that defines the new sem_init().

Now, after the addition of library B to the compilation, I saw that instead of sem_init from semaphore.h, the new sem_init was called from library B.

I know that calling functions with the same name is an awful idea, but within a large project, it can happen unintentionally.

The question: why did this happen??? Why linker has chosen the new sem_init??? Why I did not get a multiple definition linkage error?

Comment: Unlike C++, I don't believe that the linker knows about **C** function signatures, so one `sem_init()` is as good as another, and if it's pulling from a library, I would imagine it just takes the first one it finds.

Comment: Please provide a [example], or at least your compile and link commands. The linker scans libraries only for unresolved symbols. Whichever library is scanned first, wins.

Comment: Is it correct that in C++ it's impossible because of name mangling?

Sorry, can't provide a minimal example, I have simplified an example in my question, actually, the project contains 10 libraries, and it is a proprietary code

Comment: It doesn't happen In large projects because large projects have naming conventions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the linker is linking static libraries it looks there for undefined symbols only and if it finds a definition, then it links it in and resolves the symbol. `sem_init` happens to come from `B` which is linked before `-lc` (the GNU C standard library which also implements POSIX `sem_init`) is linked, and hence the linker picks up `sem_init` from `B` and then never looks for `sem_init` again, this is why you don't get multiple symbol definition error.

`B` library probably doesn't intend to implement POSIX `sem_init` with a different parameter list. It probably needs to mark its `sem_init` as `static` so that it is not visible to other translation units. And/or use a completely different name for it.

Comment: thank you very much. it was new to me. I was almost sure that functions having the same name but different signatures, will not be interchangeable for each other in C. 

In C++ it's impossible because of name mangling, am I correct?

Comment: @user3518295 You are right, C++ name mangling encodes parameter types into the mangled function name.

Comment: Thank you once again! And why in this situation (with C code) multiple definition linkage error did not occur?

A multiple definition linkage error it is the error that should prevent the situation when linker does not know which symbol definition to pick up to resolve unresolved symbol, not?

Comment: @user3518295 I answered that in the 1st paragraph, that's how linking against libraries works. You get multiple definition linker error only when you link multiple `.o` files with duplicate symbol definition into an executable or shared library.